# How to find power of 11 or x is power n in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, data-structures

I am trying to find `11`  power of `n`. I know in JavaScript there is a function `Math.pow` which give you power of number.I want to implement that function by own.**my function is working perfectly** , but its time complexity is **O(n)** can we reduce that time complexity using any other method?

I am thinking to use `bit map`, but not getting success.

```js
function power(x,n) {
    let sum =1
    for(let i =0;i<n;i++){
    sum*=x
    }
    
    return sum
}

console.log(power(11,3))
```

Comment: is a power sign `**` allowed? why not and what is?

Comment: Have you heard of exponentiation by squaring?

Comment: You can use the idea that x^n = x^(n/2) * x^(n/2) when n is even

Comment: And then special case the odd power. So you can reduce complexity to `O(log(n))` in this way

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method)?

Comment: Does it really matters if it's O(N) ? You can return `sum` as soon as `sum === Infinity` 
 -> `power(2, 1024)`

Comment: @user268396 how to acheive `O(logn)`

Comment: Are `log` and `exp` functions allowed to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the proposed square approach.

The complexity is O(log<sub>2</sub>(n)), like this table with the counts of the function.

```
   n     counts
-------  ------
   100      7
  1000     10
 10000     14
100000     17
```

```js
function power(x, n) {
    if (n === 1) return x;
    let temp = power(x, n >> 1);
    return n % 2
        ? x * temp * temp
        : temp * temp;
}

console.log(power(11, 3)); // 1331 with 2 calls
```

Comment: @naina what is complexity ?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

```js
function power(x, n) {
  let res = 1;
  let acc = x;
  while (n > 0) {
    if (n & 1) res *= acc;
    acc *= acc;
    n >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(power(11, 0)); // 1
console.log(power(11, 1)); // 11
console.log(power(11, 2)); // 121
console.log(power(11, 3)); // 1331
console.log(power(11, 5)); // 161051
console.log(power(11, 8)); // 214358881 etc.
```

The idea is memoizing the results of subsequent squaring of the original number (x). At each step n is halved, so it's O(log n) instead of O(n). It's quite similar to @NinaScholz solution, but is iterative, not recursive (which I actually consider a benefit).

*(and yes, in any real world app there should definitely be a check for MAX_SAFE_INTEGER as well, but I suppose we're discussing an algorithm here)*

Comment: what is complexity ?

Comment: seems like O(log(n)) for me, but I'm not really good for reading these

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward JS implementation of the squre approach:

```
function exp_by_squaring(x,n){
   if(n < 0) 
     return exp_by_squaring(1 / x, -n);
   else if(n === 0) 
     return  1;
   else if(n === 1) 
     return  x ;
   else if(n %2===0) 
     return exp_by_squaring(x * x,  n / 2);
   else 
     return x * exp_by_squaring(x * x, (n - 1) / 2);
}
```

I also created a benchmark with some of the approaches from other answers, have a look:

[Benchmark](https://jsben.ch/vgDBo)

Comment: That benchmark is meaningless because you just compute the same power over and over. This is likely optimized away somehow.

Comment: Each test should be independent, so the memory should be flushed between the tests

Comment: You're still always computing `pow(11, 3)` which will perform roughly the same for all methods. At least you need a larger exponent to see a significant difference.

Comment: yes, i agree on this, on bigger computation the difference is more remarcable. in the link OP is free to change the values and notice the differences.

Answer (score -1):

This appears quicker than your original implementation, although not elegant

```
function power(x,n){
   return Array.apply(null,Array(n)).reduce((r,v) => r*x, 1)
}
```

Comment: This will always be slower, as `reduce` and `apply` contains overheads

Comment: If you really think it's quicker, please provide with a proof or any meaningful explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I am not yet able to just comment on your question but I hope I understand your question good enough. Is this something you are looking for?

```js
const myPow = (x, y) => x ** y;
```